# Quotient of Dihedral groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $D_{2n}$ be the dihedral group of order $2n$, where $n$ is an even integer. 
We know that $H=\langle \sigma^{\frac{n}{2}} \rangle$ is a normal subgroup in $D_{2n}$. What about $D_{2n}/H$? And is it true that $D_{2n}$ is isomorphic to $D_n \times H$?

I think that $D_{2n}/H=D_n$. In fact, I consider the map the generators of $D_{2n}$ to those of $D_n$. It is surjective by definition (I sent generators in generators, it suffices, right?). Moreover, the kernel is $D_{n}$, since $\sigma^{\frac{n}{2}}$ goes to $\sigma'^{\frac{n}{2}}=Id$ and then I use the first isomorphism theorem.

Is my attempt to the first question correct? I have no clue for the second part.

Comment: What is $|H|$ (the order)? So what is $|D_{2n} / H|$?

Comment: $|H|=2$ and $|D_{2n}/H|=n$.

Comment: In your proof you need to check out that multiplication is preserved; easy by looking at the relations satisfied by the generators - but needs done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your two questions are:

1. yes (your proof of $D_{2n}/H\cong D_n$ is correct)
2. no if $n>2$ ($D_{2n}$ is not isomorphic  to $D_n\times C_2$: $D_{2n}$ has an element of order $n$ and $D_n$ doesn't) but yes if $n=2.$

Answer (score 0):

The dihedral group $D_{2k}$ has $k+2$ elements satisfying $x^2=1$.

So the dihedral group $D_{4k}$ has $2k+2$ elements satisfying $x^2=1$.

And the group $D_{2k}\times C_2$ has $2k+4$ elements satisfying $x^2=1$.

So $D_{4k}\not\simeq D_{2k}\times C_2$.